# jQuery only retrieves certain words from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

When I search for a word in my dictionary service to an API through jQuery, I'm only receiving certain words back and all plural words, for example:

I can search for 'word' and get definitions, but then I search for 'words' the only response is 'Plural for word'. But when I search for 'test', I get nothing back, when there are definitions when you search for the URL in a web browser.

I feel the problem is in the part below:

```
if (json !== "No definition has been found.")
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#term').focus(function(){
 var full = $("#definition").has("definition").length ? true : false;
  if(full === false){
    $('#definition').empty();
}
});

var getDefinition = function(){

var word = $('#term').val();

 if(word === ''){

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter a word.</h2>");

 } 

else {

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");

    $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=" +word+ "&pretty=true&callback=?", function(json) {

       if (json !== "No definition has been found."){
           var meanings = "";
            json["tuc"].forEach(function(tuc) {
                tuc["meanings"].forEach(function(m) {
                    meanings += "<p>"+m["text"]+"</p>\n";

                });
            });

             $("#definition").html(meanings);
          } 

else {
             $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=&pretty=true" + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img id="thedefinition" src=' + json.definition[0].image.url + ' />');
             });
          }
     });

  }

return false;
};

$('#search').click(getDefinition);
$('#term').keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
   getDefinition();
}
});

});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
    <meta name="Dictionary" content="A dictionary web service">
    <title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dictionary.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="top">

            <header>

                <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>

            </header>

        </div>

        <div id="app">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a word..." id="term" />
            <button id="search">Define!</button>

        <section id="definition">

        </section>

        </div>

        <footer>

            <p>Created by Matthew Hughes</p>

        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

If anyone has any ideas or had a similar problem, please comment!

Comment: Could you add this code to a jsFiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UznY7/

Comment: `meanings` is not a child of `tuc` when you search for `test`.

Comment: Yeah just realised that, but it is a child for other words. Is there any way around this?

Comment: `if(obj.hasOwnProperty('meaning'))`

Comment: Would this go at the end of the original if statement or outside? - I'm new to javascript, please excuse my lack of knowledge!